# Why 'Transparent' parameter in OpenLayers is a server side property?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-service

There are four parameters for WMS Layers: Name, URL, Server Side Params, OpenLayers Options. Transparent Parameter comes under Server Side Params.

Does it mean that transparent images are pre-cached in the GeoServer and return to browser on request. Can transparency be a OpenLayers Property too?

Where can I see all possible server side parameters in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are dealing with WMS services, you need to pass it certain parameters in the GetMap request. with Openlayers, you usually pass it to the params object.

The [WMS class](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html) Documentation says:

> Properties added to this object will be added to the WMS GetMap
>   requests used for this layer’s tiles.  The only mandatory parameter is
>   “layers”.  Other common WMS params include “transparent”, “styles” and
>   “format”.

So if you pass `transparent:true` parameter to your layer, it actually passes the parameter to the WMS server, which returns transparent PNG Tiles.

I have also tested sending different parameters like `sld` and `bgcolor` for my Geoserver, since these parameters are used by the [WMS GetMap](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) request.

Comment: can I use only format/png property without mentioning transparent:true?

Comment: Yes; You can do so by using format:'image/png'